# Changing text color on changing background

Tags: android, android-layout

How do I change the text color for all the activities when user selects a different color background in the first activity?

Comment: Your question is off-topic! please take a look at [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Since you said “all activities”, you can simply set the Color value in sharedpreferences when a user changes the background. You can simply read this Color value while starting any activity.

Comment: Yep.. You can save it as a hex and reference it in all the other activities texts.